# Activity indicator timing

Tags: objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

If I've got code like this:

```
....
// start activity indicator
[class callMethod];
// stop activity indicator
...
```

If `[class callMethod]` takes 10 seconds (as an example), the indicator will be animated in this time right? After calling the method the code will be blocked?

Answer (score 0):

Only if you call the `[class callMethod]` on any thread other than main (because this will block UI, which will in turn block the indicator from spinning.